# Alternatives to depreciated "setWiredHeadsetOn" to control microphone input

Tags: java, android, deprecated, android-audiomanager, headset

I am working on an app that will switch off or ignore the internal microphone in preference for the headset microphone. I found an app that does something similar (Lesser AudioSwitch) and it works well on the particular phone I am working with. I have seen a lot of people in the past direct to the `audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn` feature, however it no longer works as it has been depreciated.

I dont see any references to alternatives and any searches direct to people looking into `audioManager.isWiredHeasetOn` which is also depreciated but people have found workarounds.

My core intent is to shut off only the devices internal microphone, and leave all other microphone options (Bluetooth, headset, etc) available.

[Update]
Currently I am looking into audioRecord.setPreferredDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET); which seems promising but it telling me that int cannot be converted to AudioDeviceInfo but I cant find any other formatting information online. (See Code Below)

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioDeviceInfo;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.AudioRecord;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch sw1;
    TextView slvtxt;
    Button btnGet;
    Context context;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    AudioRecord audioRecord;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        audioManager = ((AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        slvtxt = findViewById(R.id.slaveText);
        sw1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        btnGet = findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sw1.isChecked()) {
audioRecord.setPreferredDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET);
              sw1.setText("isChecked");
            }

            else {
                sw1.setText("isNotChecked");
audioRecord.setPreferredDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

However this posts the following error...

"setPreferredDevice
(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)
in AudioRecord cannot be applied
to
(int)" Which I am unsure how to handle because this seems letter to letter the way the documentation suggests it should be set.